# T-sql: ranking groups by changed positive values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is some data in a table:

```
    date   finance
    1      5 (income)
    3     -3 (spending)
    4     -1 (spending)
    5     10 (income)
    9     -2 (spending)
   10     -3 (spending)
   15     -3 (spending)
```

Every positive value forms a group, each group begins with a positive value and includes all the negative values before the next posivitve value.

So I have to identify groups like this:

```
    date  finance  rank
    1      5       group 1  
    3     -3       group 1
    4     -1       group 1

    5     10       group 2
    9     -2       group 2
   10     -3       group 2
   15     -3       group 2
```

Dates always grow and are never the same.

Is that possible with window functions t-sql? What is the optimal way to get this result?

Comment: Is the income or spending(as strings) in the table or just your explanation?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  Analysis functions were greatly enhanced in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: This is SQL 2012. That would be interesting for me to find a solution based on only window functions, but nested window functions are not supported even in 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little trashy but it appears to work

```
SELECT [date], finance 
    , 'group ' 
        + rtrim((SELECT count(1) FROM #Tmp WHERE finance > 0 AND [date] < t.[date])  
            + CASE WHEN finance > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Group'
FROM #Tmp t
```

Comment: counting all previous positive values for every row -- that's perefct

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your grouping is quite dependent on the order of the rows.

Assuming you have a Row# [R] in your source table the following code should work.

```
--FIND ROWS WITH POSITIVE VALUE
SELECT R2=DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY R), R
INTO #TEMP
FROM <SOURCE_TABLE>
WHERE FINANCE>0

--CREATE GROUPS BY DETECTING STARTING ROW AND ENDING ROW (ENDING ROW BEING 1 LESS THAN NEXT STARTING ROW)
SELECT GROUP_N=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LOW.R)    --ASSIGN GROUP #S IN THE SAME ORDER AS THEY APPEAR IN THE SOURCE TABLE
    ,R_START=LOW.R, R_END=(HIG.R-1)
INTO #TEMP2
FROM #TEMP LOW
JOIN #TEMP HIG
    ON LOW.R2=(HIG.R2-1)
UNION
--LAST GROUP STARTS AT THE LAST DETECTED STARTING ROW AND ENDS AT THE LAST ROW OF THE SOURCE TABLE
SELECT R_START_LAST_GROUP=(SELECT MAX(R) FROM #TEMP), R_END_LAST_GROUP=(SELECT MAX(R) FROM <SOURCE_TABLE>)

--GET SOURCE DATA AND APPEND GROUP #
SELECT DAT.*, GRP.GROUP_N
FROM #TEMP2 GRP
JOIN <SOURCE_TABLE> DAT
    ON DAT.R BETWEEN GRP.R_START AND GRP.R_END
```